# Use "latest" ECR Image in CDK Lambda Build

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I have a CDK build where currently I have it as two different stacks.

Stack one is to build ECR image from Docker.

Stack two is for the remainder of my CloudFormation application, including a Lambda function that uses the image created in Stack one.

Currently, I have to manually select the new image in Lambda after the CDK pipeline finishes. I've done a fair amount of research before posting this question, and can't seem to find a definitive answer. It appears that I should not use the tag "lastest", which is fine. I'm currently using 1.0. I can change that number before running the CDK, and then the Lambda will automatically be linked to the "latest" ECR image. But I want to leave the image number as-is for the foreseeable future, run the CDK and have it automatically refer to the latest 1.0 image.

Comment: Can you share some CDK code to represent what you currently have, and where you're creating your Lambda?